# Compiler generated constructor to initialise members

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14

Is there a way to get the (MSVC) compiler to generate the following ctor' following the initializer list pattern pattern below which takes arguments in order of member deceleration instead of (or as well as) the default constructor ?

```
struct Foo{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;

    Foo(float _a, float _b, float _c) : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c) {}
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It already does, because your example is a [POD aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) type.

```
struct Foo{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
};
```

So you can initialize a `Foo` with something like

```
Foo f{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
```

Which is the same syntax as your manually defined constructor

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/5nhj)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that syntactically its different ? Foo{...} instead of Foo(...), but close enough I guess. Maybe its too much to ask from the standard or the compiler, perhaps its more of a nicety that an IDE or plugin may be able to generate so there is less typing involved.

Comment: @SaharshBishnoi https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax

Answer (score 0):

You may use `std::tuple`

```
struct Foo : private std::tuple<float, float, float>{
    using std::tuple<float, float, float>::tuple;

    const float& a() const {std::get<0>(*this);}
    float& a() {std::get<0>(*this);}
    const float& b() const {std::get<1>(*this);}
    float& b() {std::get<1>(*this);}
    const float& c() const {std::get<2>(*this);}
    float& c() {std::get<2>(*this);}
};
```

but I think it is worst than writing constructor.